# Character Array Initialization:add NUL at the end

Tags: c, arrays, character

Example:

```
char s[]={'I',' ','a','m',' ','a',' ','g','o','o','d',' ','g','u','y','\O'};

char s[]={'I',' ','a','m',' ','a',' ','g','o','o','d',' ','g','u','y',};
```

Is it always necessary to initialize character array with NUL at the end? Will the second example work if no NUL is added? And also, why do we have to add Nul at the end?

Comment: Is that a `\O`? (slash followed by a letter O) It should be `\0` (slash followed by the digit 0)

Comment: Btw for a character array of unknown length is automatically assigned with `NULL` if declare this way `char s[]="this is string"`

Comment: @CherubimAnand: There is a difference between a character array and a C-"string"!

Comment: "Will the second example work ..." - Caoont be answered without more context. Maybe reading about C-"strings" and how they are related to `char []` is a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it always necessary to initialize character array with NULL at the end

Not always. It is necessary when you want your character array to behave like a string.

So, if you just want to read and write to that array like a normal array, the `NUL` (btw, it is `NUL`, and *not* `NULL`) is not needed at the end. But, if you want to use string functions like `strlen()` or similar on that, the `NUL` is needed.

---

> Will the second example work if no NULL is added

The second example will work totally fine till you treat it like any normal array and not like a string. Meaning, if you do not use string functions like `strlen()` or similar or it, it should work fine.

Comment: Wonderful answerd. I think it is also needed if you want to print out the string. Like with printf("This is the string: %s", s);

Comment: @Matputer `NUL` means `'\0'` or `0` (which are the same) while `NULL` is a macro which expands to `(void*)0` (This macro may vary on different systems)

Comment: is there any difference between `NUL` and `NULL`?

Comment: @CoolGuy Thank you :) I delete the comment i asked before by mistake

Comment: @Matputer Google 'NUL VS NULL' for more info on that.